# What is a good practice for setting password and database user in codeigniter 4.0?

Tags: database, codeigniter

I am configuring my database in the Database.php file on codeigniter 4.0:

```
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'database' => 'mydatabase',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
];
```

Is it a good practice to put the username and password directly as a string or is there any other ideal method for importing these values?

Comment: The best way is to store the credentials in environment variables.

Comment: But when I go to production I don't use the .env file, how would I do it in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In CI3 I configure it the same as you, but security is fine when you use CI syntax to handle queries with the query helper.
you can read the documentation here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/helpers.html?highlight=query%20helper